# When displaying a simple table of one cell, the table displays roughly twice the size it should

Tags: html, css

*Browser: Chrome (displaying at 100%)
Desktop Monitor: 4K*

When displaying a simple table of one cell, the table displays roughly twice the size it should.  Just as though you zoomed in 200%.

I have a 4K desktop monitor and the table should display the full width 3840px and a height of 2560px.  But the table is displaying twice that size.

How do I display this table so it fits correctly on my screen (3840 x 2560)?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 3840px;
  height: 2560px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; //or 100%;
}
```

Comment: That will probably work.  But!  I want to place an image in the table and create an image map.  As you probably know, image maps don't work with dimension percentages.  They require absolute.

Answer (score 0):

As Blackbar said you are better off using a percentage width and height, or vh and vw:

```
table {
    width: 100vw:
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This is because 1px in CSS is not necessarily 1px on your screen. From [this site](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/):

> With the advent of higher density screens, we are seeing devices with 2 device pixels per CSS pixel (the Apple Retina, for instance) as well as displays with fractional pixel ratios.
>
> For example, on a 300dppi (device pixel per inch) screen the ratio of device pixels to CSS pixels pixels is 300/96 = 3.125